# How can I disable a submit button when click and recover it when close a dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog

suppose I have a form like

```
<form id='search'>
...
<input name="submit" type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

when click, I can disable it by

```
$('form').submit(function() {
      $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

which provent double click. My question is that: as I also set the submit will open a dialog, then how can I remove the `disabled` property by add a function to the `close:` part of that dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
close: function () {
    $('#search input[type="submit"]:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

or

```
$('#search input[type="submit"]:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: It works for me. By the way did your two answer has difference? I mean did they work for IE, chrome and ff in the older version, such as IE6?

Comment: @vanabel both work just fine, the logic behind them is different. One sets it to false the other one completely removes it.